# Unable to pass Array from Angular 2 typescript to Spring Java

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I am trying to pass a String array from my typescript

```
tmp : Array<string> = [];
```

So I have a function which takes in this array as a parameter input

```
passValues(test : Array<string>) {
   ........
   // some method to call post method from service
}
```

So in service

```
public passingOfValues( test : Array<string> ) : Observable<Array<string>> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers); 

    let response = this.http.post(this.basePath + this.modulePath + '/getArrayValue', {'test' : test }, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
            return response;
}
```

But I am getting errors such as System property [org.owasp.esapi.devteam] is not set

And I read on other posts that I have to stringify the array before passing to backend.

Is there a reason why I need to stringify / also can I just pass the raw array?

EDIT 1 :
including backend controller codes

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getArrayValues( ArrayList<String> test ) {
     logger.debug("@@@ Test if array has a size @@@" + test.size());


}
```

Apparently size already shows 0 from here.

EDIT 2 :

While debugging, i realised that the SQL at the back is receiving 
say

```
HOME CHARACTER(20 OCTETS)
```

does this make any difference?
Like passing of string into octets or do I have to do some conversion?

Sorry if I have alot of questions am also working hard on debugging and learning more about it!

Comment: Can you update how you get the data en backend?

Comment: Done! is that enough information?

Comment: Thanks for the swift actions @DaveyDaveDave ! really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the developers like JSON data as request and it's good practice in RESTful apis. why?

JSON format is `{key1: value1, key2: value 2,....}`

You are passing

`this.http.post(this.basePath + this.modulePath + '/getArrayValue',{'test' : YOUR_ACTUAL_ARRAY})`

form the front-end. The `httpClient.post(url,body,options?)` has `url` and `body` as mandatory. How can you get it in back-end? Since you have body only,

```
    public ResponseEntity<?> getArrayValues(@RequestBody List<String> test) {    
       // codes
    }
```

> Key of passed parameter from front-end `test` and variable which
>   listens in back-end should be in same name. Otherwise
>   `@RequestBody("KEY_NAME") List<String> any_variable`

As you asked from comment, you may have two key value pairs. Eg : `{ "test" : value1, "tmp": value2}`. Assume `value1` and `value2` both are String array.

`this.http.post(this.basePath + this.modulePath + '/getArrayValue',{'myJson' : YOUR_JSON})`

There are lot of way(Eg : Gson,ObjectMapper etc). I use another way.

Create a class called TestTmpConverter

```
class TestTmpConverter{
    List<String> test;
    List<String> tmp;

    //No-argument constructors & Argument constructors
    //Getters
}
```

In controller

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getArrayValues(@RequestBody List<TestTmpConverter> myJson ) {
    List<TestTmpConverter> test=myJson.getTest();
    List<TestTmpConverter> tmp=myJson.getTmp();

    // Do your work

}
```

I only showed one way.There are a lot of way to pass data to back-end like `@RequestParam, @PathVariable etc`. I feel now you get something how you can pass the data.

Comment: Hey varman this is new to me! but nice explaination i needed this,
One thing tho, from your method, you are passing in a json object correct? if this is the case where and how do i declare this json object in the ts file?

Comment: There are many ways. You can `let x={key1:value1,key2:value2}` like hard coding. Or define a class/interface with properties. Then set the value to properties which automatically makes as a json object

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @varman, your comment made me realised how much knowledge i lacked! I will be sure to study more on this. Thanks! although i used a different approach to solve my codes but your comment did help me understand some stuff

Comment: With pleasure, wave me if you need any help, as I and you said, there are a lot of method to solve averything. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

For your client put your data directly on POST's body:

```
public passingOfValues( test : Array<string> ) : Observable<Array<string>> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers); 

    let response = this.http.post(this.basePath + this.modulePath + '/getArrayValue',
                  test, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
            return response;
}
```

On your REST service use the `@RequestBody` annotation:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getArrayValues(@RequestBody String[] test ) {
     logger.debug("@@@ Test if array has a size @@@" + test.size());


}
```

Comment: May i know the difference between putting it directly and within curly braces { } ?

Comment: The format will be different: without the `{}`, you'll post `[value1, value2, value3]`, and with them, `{"test": [value1, value2, value3]}`.

Comment: @mbojko i will definately test out your suggestion!
One more quick question what if my function takes in two values? 
initially i did

{ "test" : test, "tmp": tmp}

Also, in this cause if test is a string it will become { "test": value} ?
and if i do it without curly braces it will be just value

Comment: `@RequestBody String[] test` is possible. For the above question , we can pass only one body inside the post method. So that if we define both varible as A JSON format, we can easily convert the json fromat to both values that you defined test and tmp. Anothe method that you can pass as a parameter along with post method

Comment: @OpkkoLim using [] means that you pass directly the array. {} means that you are passing an object (in your case, inside the object there is the array).

Comment: @varman say if i change the function to take in two input params, one array one string, i have to use a curly brace to pass in like 
```
{ test, tmp }
``` 
because i can only pass one body inside the post method right?

I still dont get why i am getting the [org.owasp.esapi.devteam] is not set error 

@xcesco yea i got it i tried adding { test , tmp } but apparently it doesn't work.

Comment: ```@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ TEST WHAT WE GOT FROM FRONT END OKAY : []```

when i passed the Array<string> from front end,

by loggerDebug has prints out [ ]  and thats all. is there a reason why the values disappear?

Comment: Hey thanks alot @xcesco you're right, the use of RequestBody is really useful, now i understand that it means to get the body portion from my frontend! thanks for your help too! appreciate it.